# How to show translate tab in theme setting in DRUPAL 8 unix theme

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

Theme settings has front page slide show, 
how to translate it in to different language

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you can translate the strings through the Drupal UI.

Because if in your theme file "your_theme.theme" all the strings are inside a t() funtion like the example bellow:

'#title' => t('Something'),

Then every string can be translated through the Drupal UI.